# Bug? "tag wiki edit privileges" aren't

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

When editing a Tag Wiki, I see this message:

> You do not yet have [tag wiki edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki). Your edit will be placed
>   in a queue until it is peer reviewed.

However, when you follow the link, you see a percentage list of privileges that does not contain `tag wiki edit privileges`. The only one that comes close is [approve tag wiki edits](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

Bug?

--jeroen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will see that 20k users (Trusted users) will be able to edit all tag wikis. Further than that, the ability to edit tag wikis is not connected to your reputation level. The requirement to edit specific a tag wiki is:

- You have at least 100 upvotes in non-community wiki answers with that tag

  - OR you are in the top 20 answerers in this tag
- You have at least 2000 reputation points

Comment: Thanks, accepted; I like both answers, but your answer explains the alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Good catch, the link is supposed to be /privileges/trusted-user

Fixed in dev