# Who can edit a tag wiki on Stack Overflow without peer review?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)
> [Bug? “tag wiki edit privileges” aren't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83092/bug-tag-wiki-edit-privileges-arent)

I'm one of the top posters in the [Wicket tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wicket/info) on Stack Overflow and have sufficient reputation points to review, but my edits to this tag wiki have to be peer reviewed.

I don't really object, as the review process is usually pretty quick, but I'm curious why.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but thanks for all your great Wicket answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user) - those with more than 20,000 reputation or a diamond.

Comment: So long as they have +5 rep on the tag.